# How to vertical align image and text inside a container

Tags: html, css

i have the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/2b80roL0/)

The code is:

```
    <div>
        <div style="width:15%; float:left; background: red;">
            <img src="C:\Users\64\Desktop\Furrycode\img\clock.png" style="width: 20%; height: auto; display: block; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
        </div>
        <div style="width:82%; float: right; background: red; padding-left:3%;">
            <p>Monday-Friday: Check-in and Check-out between 8am-11am and 3pm-5pm.</p>
            <p>Saturday: Check-in between 9am-11am. Check-out between 9am-3pm.</p>
            <p>Sundays/Public Holidays: Check-in and Check out between 11am-1pm.</p>
            <p>(Please note we are closed Good Friday, Easter Sunday, Christmas Day and Boxing Day).</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

I really need them to align vertically (for resposive porpuses).

Thank you so much.

Comment: What CSS have to tired so far?

Comment: What elements do you want to align vertically? It's not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, the question have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: middle`and set them to `display: inline-block` and remove the floats to the div´s

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <div style="width:15%; background: red; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
            <img src="C:\Users\64\Desktop\Furrycode\img\clock.png" style="width: 20%; height: auto; display: block; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
        </div>
        <div style="width:82%; background: red; padding-left:3%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
            <p>Monday-Friday: Check-in and Check-out between 8am-11am and 3pm-5pm.</p>
            <p>Saturday: Check-in between 9am-11am. Check-out between 9am-3pm.</p>
            <p>Sundays/Public Holidays: Check-in and Check out between 11am-1pm.</p>
            <p>(Please note we are closed Good Friday, Easter Sunday, Christmas Day and Boxing Day).</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/128/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a silly question but i really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using floats the positions of your divs will try to fit inline. I would make you divs 100% width if you would like them to be on top of each other. Here is the altered code.

```
 <div>
      <div style="width:100%; float:left; background: red;">
           <img src="C:\Users\64\Desktop\Furrycode\img\clock.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
      </div>
      <div style="width:100%; float: left; background: red; text-align: center;">
        <p>Monday-Friday: Check-in and Check-out between 8am-11am and 3pm-5pm.</p>
        <p>Saturday: Check-in between 9am-11am. Check-out between 9am-3pm.</p>
        <p>Sundays/Public Holidays: Check-in and Check out between 11am-1pm.</p>
        <p>(Please note we are closed Good Friday, Easter Sunday, Christmas Day and Boxing Day).</p>
    </div>
```